# How to typehint np.nan, value input and function return

Tags: numpy, type-hinting

For example, if i have:

```py
def f(x):
    return x
```

Where `x` is expected to be a NaN value - how's that supposed to be typehinted?

If i hint with `np.nan` i get the error: `error: Variable "numpy.nan" is not valid as a type`. I *could* use `np.float64`, but this feels too broad for what i want here.

eg:

```py
def f(x : np.nan) -> np.nan:
    return x
```

Comment: `np.nan` is just a specific value of type `float`.  It may be special, but it is still an instance, not a class or type.

Comment: @hpaulj right - so how would one ensure that `np.nan` is passed - I guess in this case it's not something that typing can do, and one would just have to catch it with some `if not np.isnan(arg): raise ValueError( ...`