# How to type hint np.nan?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that calculates a machine's "status" value - either on (`1`) or off (`0`). But also I want it to return a `np.nan` if the input value is `None` or `nan` (like what pandas would do. My goal is to apply this on a pd.DataFrame).

```py
def calc_status(raw_value: int) -> int:
    if raw_value is None or np.isnan(raw_value):
        return np.nan
    # do other checks & calcs
    return status
```

Since the function will only return 1/0 integers, the return type hint can be `Literal[0, 1]`.
But the function can also return `nan`... `type(np.nan)` is `float`. I don't want to hint `Union[Literal[0, 1], float]`, because that "float" feels too generic. The function can't just return *any* floats, such as 1.5 or 1.0. It can *only* return nan, which turns out to be a "float".

At first I tried `Literal[0, 1, np.nan]`, but that seems to be invalid, with PyCharm's static type checker showing this warning:

> 'Literal' may be parameterized with literal ints, byte and unicode strings, bools, Enum values, None, other literal types, or type aliases to other literal types

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646845/how-to-typehint-np-nan-value-input-and-function-return

Comment: No; I got the `Literal[0, 1, np.nan]` from there. PyCharm shows that warning when using `Literal[np.nan]`.

Comment: side-note: return an Enum - that's the easy way to do it.